# Cookie doesn't set from the second restart

Tags: php, cookies

my site with cloudflare correctly set a cookie for the first launch but if i try to close and clean the browser it doesn't set the cookie again. Thanks if you reach to help me.

```
setcookie( 'opt_in', from_italy_ok, time() + 60*60*24*365, '/', 'zxxx.com');
```

It only works the first time that i launch the site. From the second attempt with a clean browser this command seems to not exist.

Thanks.

Comment: Provide an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), please. If i would copy this into a php file and execute it over and over again, it would just do exactly that. Is `from_italy_ok` a constant? Otherwise it would throw a warning (Warning: Use of undefined constant from_italy_ok - assumed 'from_italy_ok' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP))

Comment: `setcookie( 'opt_in', from_italy_ok, time() + 60*60*24*365, '/', 'zxxx.com');` wouldnt work because you restrict the cookie with your 5th parameter to `'zxxx.com'` only. Just showing your page does not provide an reproducible example. **we dont know the rest of your coding, we just see one line here, where if i remove the last parameter it works for me on my local machine.**

Comment: Disable CloudFlare caching and re-try.

Comment: ALREADY DONE. DOESN'T WORK

Comment: SOLVED IT WAS THE W3 TOTAL CACHE PLUGIN. NOW I ACTIVATED THE WP SUPER CACHE AND IT WORKS FINE.